# Undo mistaken chown of /usr/bin on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, mac, bash, chown

I made a huge mistake. I wanted to change permissions for `/usr/local/bin`, but changed permissions for `/usr/bin` instead. Now I can't use `sudo` and others. I tried to change it back, but operation is not permitted.

Please help me to resolve this, or tell me, should I reinstall macOS? And if it is possible to:

1. Make a backup with Time Machine
2. Reinstall Mac OS
3. Restore with Time Machine

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try booting on the recovery partition (hold option down during boot) and use the terminal there to reset. I think you can also use disk utility to repair permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SOLVED] After a lot of surfing I did it!
God bless this guy: https://askubuntu.com/users/10962/user10962
There is the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/471503/528411

I used Recovery Mode (Cmd+R on start or reboot), after that you need to choose Utilities -> Terminal. In terminal go to Volume what you use and if you got same problem as me execute "chown root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo"

Comment: Could you post the essential parts of the post there, in case the original post got deleted - and with respect to macOS? How do you get into root on a mac, for example?

Comment: I used Recovery Mode (Cmd+R on start or reboot), after that you need to choose Utilities -> Terminal. In terminal go to Volume what you use and if you got same problem as me execute "chown root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo"